# Changing Jasper Report layout to run from left to right

Tags: java, layout, jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible to create a jasper report that runs from left to right as opposed to the usual top to bottom layout.

Basically having the header band of the report running vertically instead of horizontally.

For example, from this:

```
Age Sex Location
35   m  London
27   F  Dublin
40   m  Dublin
```

To this layout:

```
Age      35      27     40
Sex      m       f       m
Location London Dublin Dublin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it by setting the text rotation to "right" and then rotating the page.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a property of the report called "Print order". Changing it from "Vertical" to "Horizontal" will do the same as your text rotation but for the entire report.

Comment: That will not put the headers on the left of the page like the example.